# Redux-Toolkit extraReducers listed after reducers causes issues (TS2322 Error)

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

## Problem

I am using Redux-Toolkit and I am having an issue with the code below. When `extraReducers` is omitted, my code works fine. When `extraReducers` is listed after `reducers`, I encounter an error (shown below). When `extraReducers` is listed *before* `reducers`, my code works fine. What am I missing here?

```
type Item = { id: string, name: string }

export const itemsAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Item>();
const initialState = itemsAdapter.getInitialState();

export const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'items',
  initialState,
  reducers: {  
    itemsAdded(state, action: PayloadAction<{ items: Item[] }>) {
      itemsAdapter.setAll(state, action.payload.items);
    }, 
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => { /*  },,
});
```

## Error Message

```
TS2322: Type '(state: WritableDraft<EntityState<Item>>, action: { payload: { items: Item[]; }; type: string; }) => void' is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<WritableDraft<EntityState<Item>> | undefined, { payload: any; type: string; }> | CaseReducerWithPrepare<WritableDraft<EntityState<Item>> | undefined, PayloadAction<...>>'.
  Type '(state: WritableDraft<EntityState<Item>>, action: { payload: { items: Item[]; }; type: string; }) => void' is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<WritableDraft<EntityState<Item>> | undefined, { payload: any; type: string; }>'.
    Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
      Type 'WritableDraft<WritableDraft<EntityState<Item>>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<EntityState<Item>>'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<EntityState<Item>>'.
```

Comment: You will have to share a little bit more code - only the code you are showing here is not very likely to cause something like that.

Comment: @phry What would cause it then?

Comment: I have no idea. You describe three code examples and show only one. It's a TypeScript error, but your repro is so incomplete nobody could actually open it in an editor and look at the errors or move code around.
Show all code examples and share them in a working TypeScript playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Comment: I ran into this question while experiencing the same problem. I opened an issue on the RTK git repo with specific conditions to repro here: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/2862

Comment: please specify the version of react, typescript & redux-toolkit. One thing which you can try is upgrading the packages to their latest version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed this by providing a type for the `builder` parameter.

```js
extraReducers: (builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<MyCustomState>) => {
  builder.addCase(myCaseReducer, (state, action) => { /* this is code */ });
}
```

This prevents typescript from inferring `MyCustomState | undefined`

Does seem like a bug, this wasn't a problem until I updated redux-toolkit